# Facebook Javascript SDK not working on Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

It seems the javascript SDK is not working at all on my domain. The like box no longer works... This happened after I created an app canvas page, I think.

I'm trying to use FB.ui on my apps canvas page but nothing with the FB js SDK is working. I figured it might be a javascript problem so I removed all of the jquery / mootools but no luck.

One thing is I don't have a secure URL yet, could this be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Secure URL is not the issue. Please check the Error console to see the errors thrown? To resolve FB Undefined issue try loading that asynchronously as suggested by facebook use the code provided here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Try loading sdk asynchronously. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/